# custom google sheet function that returns file ID from the name of a file in google drive

Tags: google-sheets-formula

My appsheet App takes in image as data and saves it in a google sheet. But the saved image is recorded as file name. I need a google sheet function that takes in name of a file in google drive & return file ID of the file so that I can make a hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

To get a file id from a file name

```
function getFileId(nameOfFile) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(nameOfFile);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    return (file.getId())
  }
}
```

but this could not be a custom function, you need to use it in a pure script.